# How does .equals Java String Class method work?

Tags: java, class, methods

In java there is a string class method that works as seen bellow. But I wonder how is it that we are able to call the method on a random variable of type string?

```
String word = "hello"
word.equals("hello");
```

output is true

Comment: What do you mean by "a random variable of type string"?

Comment: In Java you can instantiate objects without assigning it to a variable. Here this is the case for `"hello"` : `word.equals("hello");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `equals()` method is used to verify if the state of the instances of two Java classes is the same. Because `equals()` is from the Object class, every Java class inherits it. But the `equals()` method has to be overridden to make it work properly. Of course, String overrides `equals()`.

Take a look:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }

    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String aString = (String)anObject;
        if (coder() == aString.coder()) {
          return isLatin1() ? StringLatin1.equals(value, aString.value)
            : StringUTF16.equals(value, aString.value);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

As you can see, the state of the String class value has to be equals() and not the object reference. It doesn’t matter if the object reference is different; the state of the String will be compared

I have taken it from [here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/3276354/java-language/java-challengers-2-string-comparisons.html). Better if you have an idea about String pool also. So please refer the link

Answer (score 1):

equals method compares the string on which the method is called with the string which is passed as a parameter.

Take a look at these links:

[String Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

[Equals on String](https://www.journaldev.com/18302/java-string-equals)

[Overriding equals in String class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255360/what-is-the-need-to-override-equals-method-in-string-class)

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing `String` with primitives like `int,long`. 
The answer is
String is not a primitive. It is a class. There are several ways to create an object from this class,
like

```
String word=new String("hello");
String word="hello"; //special case for String class
```

now `word` becomes an object and you can call the method `equals`(because every object you create is inherited from java.lang.Object) class.

If you look at primitives like `int`.
you cannot do something like below, beacause `number` is not an object.

```
int number=12; 
number.equals(12)
```

Answer (score 1):

[String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class (String in Java is Object) inherited equals method from Object and override it as is correctly mentioned in answers by Sand and Armine.

We can call methods on String (even on constant String, statement: "Hello World".length() returns 11) **because String is an Object and not a primitive type**. Primitive types are byte, short, int,... You could read more about them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Nice reading about differences between primitives types and Objects: [Difference between Primitive and Reference variable in Java](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/09/difference-between-primitive-and-reference-variable-java.html)